# Pull RSS feed using Jquery .get; cross domain issues?

Tags: javascript, rss, get-request

I have been trying to get the example from [How to parse an RSS feed using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-a-rss-feed-using-javascript) working. My HTMl/script is below. The *get* request isn't working. I'm not getting any errors, just nothing happening.
Is this because of cross-domain issues? Can anyone spot the issue? Ultimately, I want to pull treasury prices from government rss feeds such as:
http://www.federalreserve.gov/feeds/Data/H15_H15_RIFSGFSW04_N.B.XML
Am I taking the right approach?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
alert('Jquery working fine');
    $.get('https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/10943544', function (data) {
    $(data).find("entry").each(function () { // or "item" or whatever suits your feed
        var el = $(this);

        console.log("------------------------");
        console.log("title      : " + el.find("title").text());
        console.log("author     : " + el.find("author").text());
        console.log("description: " + el.find("description").text());
});
});

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
```

Comment: The answer is yes it's a cross-domain issue, but "nothing" is not happening, you will be getting a notice `XMLHttpRequest cannot load (url) No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`. You can, instead, bounce the request via your local server.

Comment: Ok thanks. Whilst there seem to be ways to circumvent the same origin policy, Im reading that it isnt something I should do. With regard to teh federal reserve rss feeds (example: http://www.federalreserve.gov/feeds/Data/H15_H15_RIFSGFSW04_N.B.XML), are they just there for internal use? why would there be RSS feeds made publicly available like this if not to access like im trying to do in this question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery YQL SELECT FROM rss variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554804/jquery-yql-select-from-rss-variable)